# "no basic auth credentials" docker push

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecr

I tried to push the Docker container. But it gave me a "no basic auth credentials" error. Even I used `aws ecr get-login-password` and entered my credentials with `docker configure` and managed to create repository from terminal in AWS, pushing did not work. Does anybody know why I cannot push to AWS?

I used `docker push <my-account-id>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/<awsrepo-details>:latest` to push the image

Thank in advance.

Comment: can you please provide command that you are using to push the image

Comment: I use ```docker push <my-account-id>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/<awsrepo-details>:latest```                                                                                                                             Thank you

Comment: `docker configure`? Did you mean `docker login`?

Comment: ```docker configure``` to provide secret access key and password.

Answer (score 5):

it is authentication, first retrieve an authentication token and authenticate your Docker client to your registry:

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region ap-south-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin {account_id}.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
```

after you build and tag, push depending on your tag:

```
docker push ${account_id}.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/${repo_name}:latest
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt help. It worked :)